# How do I "expand" an ant path (accessed with refId=..) to all files in the path except some?

Tags: ant

I am trying to get ant4eclipse to work and I have used ant a bit, but not much above a simple scripting language.  We have multiple source folders in our Eclipse projects so the example in the ant4eclipse documentation needs adapting:

Currently I have the following:

```
<target name="build">

  <!-- resolve the eclipse output location -->
  <getOutputpath property="classes.dir" workspace="${workspace}" projectName="${project.name}" />

  <!-- init output location -->
  <delete dir="${classes.dir}" />
  <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />

  <!-- resolve the eclipse source location -->
  <getSourcepath pathId="source.path" project="." allowMultipleFolders='true'/>

  <!-- read the eclipse classpath -->
  <getEclipseClasspath pathId="build.classpath" 
                          workspace="${workspace}" projectName="${project.name}" />

  <!-- compile -->
  <javac destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="build.classpath" verbose="false" encoding="iso-8859-1">
    <src refid="source.path" />
    </javac>

  <!-- copy resources from src to bin -->
  <copy todir="${classes.dir}" preservelastmodified="true">
    <fileset refid="source.path">
        <include name="**/*"/>
        <!--
        patternset refid="not.java.files"/>
        -->
    </fileset>
  </copy>
</target>
```

The  task runs successfully, but I cannot get the  to work - it is supposed to copy all non-java files over too to emulate the behaviour of eclipse.

So, I have a pathId named source.path which contains multiple directories, which I somehow needs to massage into something the copy-task like.  I have tried nesting  which is not valid, and some other wild guesses.

How can I do this - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`foreach`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) task from the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net) library:

```
<target name="build">
    ...

    <!-- copy resources from src to bin -->
    <foreach target="copy.resources" param="resource.dir">
        <path refid="source.path"/>
    </foreach>
</target>

<target name="copy.resources">
    <copy todir="${classes.dir}" preservelastmodified="true">
        <fileset dir="${resource.dir}" exclude="**/*.java">
    </copy>
</target>
```

If your `source.path` contains file paths as well then you could the [`if`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) task (also from ant-contrib) to prevent attempting to copy files for a file path, e.g.

```
<target name="copy.resources">
    <if>
        <available file="${classes.dir}" type="dir"/>
        <then>
            <copy todir="${classes.dir}" preservelastmodified="true">
                <fileset dir="${resource.dir}" exclude="**/*.java">
            </copy>
        </then>
    </if>
</target>
```

Comment: This was what I ended up doing.  Note, that for any reasonably complete Eclipse emulating build system this grows out of control.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using [`pathconvert`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) to build a pattern that `fileset includes` can work with.

```
<pathconvert pathsep="/**/*," refid="source.path" property="my_fileset_pattern">
    <filtermapper>
        <replacestring from="${basedir}/" to="" />
    </filtermapper>
</pathconvert>
```

That will populate `${my_fileset_pattern}` with a string like:

```
1/**/*,2/**/*,3
```

if `source.path` consisted of the three directories 1, 2, and 3 under the basedir.  We're using the `pathsep` to insert wildcards that will expand to the full set of files later.

The property can now be used to generate a fileset of all the files.  Note that an extra trailing `/**/*` is needed to expand out the last directory in the set.  Exclusion can be applied at this point.

```
<fileset dir="." id="my_fileset" includes="${my_fileset_pattern}/**/*">
    <exclude name="**/*.java" />
</fileset>
```

The copy of all the non-java files then becomes:

```
<copy todir="${classes.dir}" preservelastmodified="true">
    <fileset refid="my_fileset" />
</copy>
```

That will copy the source files over retaining the source directory structure under `todir`.  If needed, the `flatten` attribute of the copy task can be set to instead make all the source files copy directly to `todir`.

Note that the pathconvert example here is for a unix fileseystem, rather than windows.  If something portable is needed, then the `file.separator` property should be used to build up the pattern:

```
<property name="wildcard" value="${file.separator}**${file.separator}*" />
<pathconvert pathsep="${wildcard}," refid="source.path" property="my_fileset">
...
```